# Selecting a GameObject in Unity Editor from MonoDevelop Debugger

Tags: debugging, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm debugging a MonoBehaviour script in MonoDevelop.

There is a way to select (in the **Unity Editor**) the `gameobject` the current paused script is attached to?

(I have multiple instances of the same prefab with that script attached, so finding it in the Hierarchy is not trivial)

Comment: By paused script do you mean a script that you are stepping through in debug mode?

Comment: yes, I'm stepping through the script in debug mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily by taking advantage of Unity's [Selection](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection.html) class. Just be sure to add `using UnityEditor;` at the top of your script.

To select the `gameObject` you are debugging in your hierarchy, simply set the `Selection.activeGameObject` property in your script right after the line you are placing your break point on.  For example:

```
void Update()
{
    int breakPoint = 5; //your breakpoint is placed here

    //select this gameObject in the hierarchy 
    Selection.activeGameObject = this.gameObject; 
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, but is it possible to do this without changing script code? (Modifying and re-run code every time is a little bit annoying...) I think not, right?

Comment: You are going to need some line of code in your script to handle the selection, as far as I know.